# Weight to mass and speed conversion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, projectile, drag

> If you dropped an 100-lb. anchor in 500 feet of ocean water how long will it take to hit the bottom?

Comment: Please, can you edit your question snowing your  attempted solution?